# How to get data from directshow filter output pin?

Tags: directshow

I have  direct show filter which takes an input and process it and give the result to outputpin.

I want to write this filter output data to a file...And i want to do it in its filter class.So i want to get the output pin buffer data.

Shortly how to reach final data of outputpin in its filter? How can i do it?

**Not:** The output pin is derived from CBaseOutputPin.This is an open source filter it "magically" :-) put wright data to its output pin which i can not figure out  how yet...

**Update:**

Here is the siutuation:

```
Media Source ---->  GFilter ----> FileWriter
```

I have source code of GFilter... I have no source code of FileWriter...What i want to make is make GFilter write its own data...I debug GFilter get some insight how its transform data but my attemp to write this data result with wrong data... So i deceide for now how to simply get data at its output pin...

**Update[2]**

In Filter outputpin somwhere the filter writer  pass the file writer pin to IStreamPtr variable...Everthing seems to written to a variable m_pIStream which is type of [IStreamPtr]

```
GFilterOutput::CompleteConnect(IPin *pReceivePin)
{


    // make sure that this is the file writer, supporting
    // IStream, or we will not be able to write out the metadata
    // at stop time
    // m_pIStream  is IStreamPtr type
    m_pIStream = pReceivePin;
    if (m_pIStream == NULL)
    {
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
    return CBaseOutputPin::CompleteConnect(pReceivePin);
}
```

...

```
GFilterOutput::Replace(LONGLONG pos, const BYTE* pBuffer, long cBytes)
{
     //OutputDebugStringA("DEBUG: Now at MuxOutput Replace");

    // all media content is written when the graph is running,
    // using IMemInputPin. On stop (during our stop, but after the
    // file writer has stopped), we switch to IStream for the metadata.
    // The in-memory index is updated after a successful call to this function, so
    // any data not written on completion of Stop will not be in the index.
    CAutoLock lock(&m_csWrite);

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if (m_bUseIStream)
    {


        IStreamPtr pStream = GetConnected();
        if (m_pIStream == NULL)
        {
            hr = E_NOINTERFACE;
        } else {
            LARGE_INTEGER liTo;
            liTo.QuadPart = pos;
            ULARGE_INTEGER uliUnused;
            hr = m_pIStream->Seek(liTo, STREAM_SEEK_SET, &uliUnused);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                ULONG cActual;
                hr = m_pIStream->Write(pBuffer, cBytes, &cActual);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && ((long)cActual != cBytes))
                {
                    hr = E_FAIL;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // where the buffer boundaries lie is not important in this 
        // case, so break writes up into the buffers.
        while (cBytes && (hr == S_OK))
        {
            IMediaSamplePtr pSample;
            hr = GetDeliveryBuffer(&pSample, NULL, NULL, 0);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                long cThis = min(pSample->GetSize(), cBytes);
                BYTE* pDest;
                pSample->GetPointer(&pDest);
                CopyMemory(pDest, pBuffer,  cThis);
                pSample->SetActualDataLength(cThis);

                // time stamps indicate file position in bytes
                LONGLONG tStart = pos;
                LONGLONG tEnd = pos + cThis;
                pSample->SetTime(&tStart, &tEnd);
                hr = Deliver(pSample);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    pBuffer += cThis;
                    cBytes -= cThis;
                    pos += cThis;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return hr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have full source code, step it through with debugger until you reach the point where your filter calls `IPin::Receive` of the peer downstream filter, update/override code there and you have full control as for writing data into file etc.

Comment: Update my info..It seems this is not valid in my situation...The GFilter class InputPin has Receive method but  GFilter output pi has no.. And i can not debug 3rd party Filter which may be calls Receive on my Filter. I want o access this inside GFilter...

Comment: "I have source code of GFilter" so you have the code. You don't need FileWriter's code, just dump the data as late as possible in GFilter before FileWriter's `IPin::Receive` is called.

Comment: Well, the filter speak with file writer via IStream interface...I just could not able to figure out where it calls FireWriter IPin::Receive... I even search Receive keyword in source code...:-)

Comment: I try also overwrite Recive method of Outpin [ may be silly ] but outpin does not support this interface... Any hint for me to figure out where filter calls FireWriter IPin::Receive method...

Comment: Everthing seems to written to a variable m_pIStream which is type of [IStreamPtr]

Comment: OK if you want to capture stuff going to `IStream`, it indeed has nothing to do with `IPin::Receive`. Well then, make your own IStream implementation and replace/hook the real pointer in member variable: GFilter will call your methods and you wil be able to process data and perhaps forward the calls to original interface pointer.